# Tkinter GIF Animation falters and is pixelated

Tags: python, animation, tkinter, gif

I made a loadingwheel animation in After Effects and i am trying to use it with tkinter in python. Although the animation is 60 frames a second, it falters and won't show the entire frame. This is my code:

```
from tkinter import * 
from PIL import Image

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1920x1080")

image1 = Image.open("LoadingWheel.gif")
framesTotal = image1.n_frames

animation = [PhotoImage(file="LoadingWheel.gif", format=f'gif -index {i}') for i in range(framesTotal)]

def update(ind):
    frame = animation[ind]
    label.configure(image=frame)
    
    ind += 1
    if ind == framesTotal:
        ind = 0

    root.after(60, update, ind)

label = Label(root)
label.pack()
root.after(0, update, 0)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: This is what happens when i run the script]

[image: This is how it should look!!]

The first image is a screenshot of how it looks when i run the script, and the second image is how it should look!

I hope someone knows how to fix this!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ImageTk.PhotoImage`

```
from tkinter import * 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
#root.geometry("1920x1080")

image1 = Image.open(r"loading.gif")
framesTotal = image1.n_frames

play_back_delay = 30
animation = []

def loadGif():
    for x in range(framesTotal):
        frame = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1.copy())
        animation.append(frame)
        image1.seek(x)


def update(ind):
    frame = animation[ind]
    label.configure(image=frame)
    
    ind += 1
    if ind == framesTotal:
        ind = 0

    root.after(play_back_delay, update, ind)

label = Label(root)
label.pack()
loadGif()
update(0)
root.mainloop()
```